# Unable to upgrade heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-postgres

I've just upgraded my heroku database. I'm now trying to copy the data from my old database to my new database, however I keep getting this error. Could it be that I'm unable to copy it because write access is revoked?

[image]

Comment: What will be printed for `heroku pg:info --app earthledhub` ?

Comment: This only shows 1 database: DATABASE_URL.
I am using a --remote staging and a --remote production environment on heroku. I am just upgrading the staging one. Have I upgraded the wrong one? :S

Comment: Which app for staging and which app for production, you may work on the wrong app I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just import and export a backup using PG Backups, your issue here is that your databases are in different apps(environments), so from the console using `--app earthedhub` will just let you use the `DATABASE_URL`.

use a PG Backups take a look to this [post](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)